# Certification failed for App Manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, app-certification-kit

Please help me to solve this error. I have tried to rectify this error multiple times. 
I have upgraded a windows phone silverlight 8.0 to windows phone silverlight 8.1 and the application is deploying and working normally on my local device but it fails certification every time.

### [image]

**Package.appxmanifest file code is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest" xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/manifest" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest">
 <Identity Name="20865PriyanshuMittal.MedicineReminder" Publisher="CN=30E3B959-D42F-4C3C-A527-4DAFDF42CD4B" Version="1.0.0.0" />
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="5fbbab69-e356-41ee-af0d-0a780eb96d7c" PhonePublisherId="D8D6EAF0-43F3-434D-AFAA-5870EB749E23" />
<Properties>
<DisplayName>Medicine Reminder</DisplayName>
<PublisherDisplayName>Priyanshu Mittal</PublisherDisplayName>
<Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
</Properties>
<Prerequisites>
<OSMinVersion>6.3.1</OSMinVersion>
<OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
</Prerequisites>
<Resources>
<Resource Language="x-generate" />
</Resources>
<Applications>
<Application Id="x5fbbab69ye356y41eeyaf0dy0a780eb96d7cx" Executable="AGHost.exe" EntryPoint="MainAsisst.xaml">
<m3:VisualElements DisplayName="Medicine Reminder" Square150x150Logo="Assets\SquareTile150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="Medicine" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646" ToastCapable="false">
<m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Assets\SquareTile71x71.png">
        </m3:DefaultTile>
        <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splashscreen.png" />
        <m3:ApplicationView MinWidth="width320" />
        <!--Used in XAML Designer. DO NOT REMOVE-->
      </m3:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="systemEvent" />
            <Task Type="timer" />
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
  </Capabilities>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>AgHostSvcs.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="AgHost.BackgroundTask" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Package>


**WMAppmanifest.xml file code**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2014/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.1">
  <DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="en-US" />
  <App xmlns="" ProductID="{5fbbab69-e356-41ee-af0d-0a780eb96d7c}" Title="Medicine Reminder" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.0.0.0" Genre="apps.normal" Author="Priyanshu Mittal" Description="Medicine" Publisher="Priyanshu Mittal" PublisherID="{D8D6EAF0-43F3-434D-AFAA-5870EB749E23}" SDOptOut="false">
    <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\images\searchsmall.png</IconPath>
    <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MAP" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
    </Capabilities>
    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainAsisst.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume" />
    </Tasks>
    <Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="doc_cardToken" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateFlip>
          <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\images\searchsmall.png</SmallImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\images\searchmedium.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Title>Medicine Reminder</Title>
          <BackContent>
          </BackContent>
          <BackBackgroundImageURI>
          </BackBackgroundImageURI>
          <BackTitle>
          </BackTitle>
          <LargeBackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\images\searchlarge.png</LargeBackgroundImageURI>
          <LargeBackContent />
          <LargeBackBackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">
          </LargeBackBackgroundImageURI>
          <DeviceLockImageURI>
          </DeviceLockImageURI>
          <HasLarge>True</HasLarge>
        </TemplateFlip>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
    <ScreenResolutions>
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WVGA" />
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WXGA" />
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_HD720P" />
    </ScreenResolutions>
  </App>
</Deployment>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629257.aspx) from MSDN in the Platform appropriate files test section.

The important part to note is that you should compile your assemblies in Neutral. The easiest way to do so is to use Visual Studio package generation (right click windows phone project, then store, then create app package) and ensure you select Neutral after you reserve an app name.